# Using empty related_name to access foreign object fields directly

Tags: django

I have three models that are very similar to eachother, and all have a foreign key to a parent model. Let's call them `Applet1`, `Applet2` and `Applet3` and all of them point to `AppletGroup`.
`Applet1` and `Applet2` has a fields `applet_group` that is a `ForeignKey`, ,but `Applet3` is not managed by my project, so it's fields are kept the same as fields that managing project for this model has.
So I have created additional model `Applet3AppletGroup`

```
class Applet3AppletGroup(models.Model):
    applet_group = models.ForeignKey(AppletGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="applet_3")
    applet_3 = models.OneToOneField(Applet3, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="applet_group_fk")

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=["applet_group", "applet_3"])]
```

And it was working like this for quite some time. But I find it not consistent as right now to access `applet_group` from `Applet1` and `Applet2` you simply access `.applet_group`, but to access it from `Applet3` I have to use `applet_group_fk__applet_group`.
I started wondering if it is safe to use `related_name=""` in `OneToOneField`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason *why* you need three `Applet` models here? Why not make one `Applet` model?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you can not use `''` as `related_name`. But even if that was possible, you should then query with `applet_group_fk____` (note the four underscores). It looks like you aim to solve a problem the wrong way.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, they are all similar but different. Where would you take `applet_group_fk` from if I would rename it to `""`? PyCharm feels like it's ok to set `related_name` to `""`, even suggests to use `applet_group` directly from `Applet3`